# Could not bind to additional port for apache via ufw on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache-2.4, ufw

I just moved our site to DigitalOcean. Their DNS servers went down. I checked and last time there was a problem involving DNS servers it took 28 hours to fix. We have a consulting gig going at a client this very moment. The consultants use the resources on our site to do the consulting. I can't hold them up for 28 hours.

I requested a floating IP address from DigitalOcean. I set up an additional apache virtual server that will listen on port 81 via that IP. We'll lose the SSL encryption, but they will be able to type in an ip address to access the site. Here is the conf file I enabled:

```
Listen new.flo.ter.ip:81
<VirtualHost new.flo.ter.ip:81>
  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  ServerName  www.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /path/to/public

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /path/to/logs/prod_error.log
  CustomLog /path/to/logs/prod_access.log combined

  <Directory /path/to/public>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

'sudo ufw status verbose' produces:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
81/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
81/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

'ps -ef | grep apache' produces:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/cm_prod_floater.conf:Listen new.flo.ter.ip:81
/etc/apache2/sites-available/cm_prod.conf:Listen main.ip.addy.00:80
/etc/apache2/sites-available/cm_prod.conf:Listen main.ip.addy.00:443
```

All other references to port addresses in ports.conf and apache2.conf are commented out.

'sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart' yields this error:

```
(99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address new.flo.ter.ip:81
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this row in your apache conf file

> Listen new.flo.ter.ip:81

If you used ubuntu put this in 
/etc/apache2/ports.conf

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot stambata. Didn't work. I know this virtual host file was enabled because I checked for the symlink.